# Firefox add-on sdk/request working

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

This is the only code I have in my index.js file:

```
var Request = require("sdk/request").Request;
Request({
  url: "https://api.zipbooks.com/",
  content: {q: "test"},
  onComplete: function (response) {
    console.log(response.text);
  }
}).post();
```

it logs nothing, the status is 0, statusText is undefined,

If you wisit https://api.zipbooks.com/ you will see a message. Why Firefox doesn't get it?

PS. It gets the response if I change the url to http://example.com/xampp/splash.php.

Comment: Try `console.error` instead of `console.log`

Comment: @Noitidart, it returns an empty string anyways.

Comment: This isnt due to the cors issue is it? I think you arent using the Request correctly, this is how it was done: https://github.com/willscott/grunt-jasmine-firefoxaddon/blob/844e85ec6c63e8886d2d218663dc3132e7286da4/tasks/jasmine-firefoxaddon/index.js#L18-L33 when you post data like that, you have to set `'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8'` i think.